How do you name an advertised coherent collection of LEGO?
I am curious how a collection of LEGO sets is called, which are depicted together in official LEGO ad material.
Like the image below, which consists of sets

7634 Red tractor
7635 4WD with Horse Trailer
7636 Combine
7637 Farm
7684 Pig farm & tractor
7566 Farmer



LEGO calls this a Theme or a Sub-theme. The picture you use as an example shows the Farm sub-theme of the City theme of sets.

Agree for this sample. But when you have for example Lego Castle which is advertised in various combinations in the folders. How do you call what is advertised together? Is it called maybe a Lego display?
